# How can I make a graphing assistant with Arduino?

Tags: arduino

So I had this idea of making a graphing assistant. Basically, It would be a camera connected to an Arduino. The camera would see a function, or a graph, take a picture, and from the picture, show on a display the Domain, function, where it does not exist, and it's derivative.

My question is how hard would it be to accomplish this? What hardware and software would I need and what concepts should I learn? I am pretty familiar with Arduino and been coding and creating projects with it for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino is not meant for developing high-end camera-based Video Processing applications. Although you can attach a camera module over SPI, capture an image and process it in your Arduino, I would highly recommend you to look for other alternatives. This is because Arduino is slow (for Computer Vision Applications) and you will end up writing a lot of code from scratch. You can instead make use of open source computer vision libraries and resources (like OpenCV) and develop your application on an SBC (Single Board Computer).

I will recommend using a [RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) along with [RaspiCam](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) and [Python](https://www.learnpython.org/) and [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/).

If you still insist on using an Arduino, you can have a look at [Pixy2](https://pixycam.com/pixy2/), which comes along with a faster co-processor to handle your Image Processing needs.